# remove elements from array knowing number of previously added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have array in javascript and I want how many elements I added before using push how can I remove from array knowing it's lenght and number of elements added before?

```
//toAdd has for example 10 elements
 $.each(toAdd, function (index, item) {
   myArr.push(item);
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure your question is very obvious. Do you want to get the array length and and remove X number of items before adding a new item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the length of the array before doing any `.push()` into:

```
  var arrLen = myArr.length;

  //toAdd has for example 10 elements
  $.each(toAdd, function (index, item) {
     myArr.push(item);
  });
```

Now if you want to reset it,  just set the length:

```
myArr.length = arrLen;
```

Comment: is this doing cut to new lenght, and rest of array is deleted ? great solution though.

Answer (score 1):

By checking the length using length property. Use `push` method to add element and use `splice` method to remove the values based on the index or use `pop` to remove top element.